# Correctly force SSL on wordpress via wp-config.php

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, https

If I edit the `wp-config.php` I am supposed to add:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
```

However, my website has `.htaccess` rules to force https and www across the entire website:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I know there are other rewriterules available, but again not sure which one is correct.

Which of the following 3 should I be using in `wp-config.php`

#### 1 - Without isset(), with curly brackets, with server_port

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
    $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;
}
```

#### 2 - Without curly brackets & without server_port?

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```

#### 3 - Are curly brackets needed/better or "more correct" & is server_port required?

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
    $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;
}
```

I've found a few other slightly different variations of this all over the internet regarding wordpress SSL but I can't figure out what one is the correct/main one...

Comment: If you're already forcing SSL via Apache's redirect rule, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @GustavoStraube appears to be behind a proxy. If that's the case the question should be modified.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

PHP code doesn't have to deal with SSL at all in such case. 
Here applies classical [SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle: if you code doesn't explicitly work with connection (in WP it does not), you should leave protocol checking to web server.

You should also avoid defining port in your rewrite rules. In case you're not using multisite WP setup, you could try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: and if using Multi-Site?

Answer (score 12):

i used this one. which is fine to go on.

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
   $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

if your server port is differed from 443. you can specify it . Otherwise, no need to use it once again .

Comment: Where should this code be placed?  I added it to functions.php and now wp-admin does not work, but the frontend still works.

Comment: @NuEverest, try placing it in `wp-config.php`.

Comment: For AWS LightSail Wordpress images, this worked for us with a LightSail LoadBalancer handling the TLS and Wordpress just serving HTTP. Be aware of FQDN's in your page cache.

`/bitnami/wordpress/wp-config.php`: `if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') { define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' ); define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' ); } else { define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' ); define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' ); }`

Comment: Thank you but please write === on the first line and add brackets, so this could be less confusing to newcomers who usually do not indent the code very well when copy-pasting. Also please mention in the answer itself that it should be put in `wp-config.php`. Now I cannot do this since the edit queue is full

Answer (score 5):

Corrected .htaccess rules ([as detailed on wiki.apache.org](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS)):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://mysslcertdomainname.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Normally, your code examples (1,2,3) are not necessary with Wordpress, but it looks like you have some kind of proxy based on the question.

1. **Not Good** Will generate a PHP warning (standard php configuration) if `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` is not set by the web server.
2. **Good** Checks variable exists before checking the value. Generates no warnings.
3. **Good** Best**

** As a general rule changing `_SERVER` variables (like `SERVER_PORT` and `HTTPS`) are discouraged unless you have a not-so-common setup (ie. behind proxy - which is the only reason for any of this code).

Comment: The one thing that is wrong with your .htaccess rule is that it doesn't force www, where as the one I posted forces both www and https? **(This is also a question, because I am not 100% sure)**

Comment: @Ryflex `mysslcertdomainname.com` is an example. For my own sites I use `%{SERVER_NAME}` - which means, "redirect to the primary server_name configured in Apache".  It really depends on what domain names are in your SSL certificate you purchased.

Comment: I only want it to force www across every single subdomain/main domain  and https acrosss just the main domain, which after www has been forced the site `www.website.com` would become `https://www.website.com` but `www.testing.website.com` would be `http://www.testing.website.com`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using docker and to avoid manual configurations (by humans) this worked for me:

```
if ( getenv('ENABLE_HTTPS')  === "true" ) {
  define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true );
  $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
}
```

And I just need to pass a new variable **ENABLE_HTTPS**

```
docker run -d --name wordpress -it --rm -p 80:80 \
-e DB_HOST=10.10.10.10:3306 \
-e DB_USER=root \
-e DB_PASSWORD=secret \
-e DB_NAME=wordpress \
-e AUTH_KEY=$RANDOM_KEY \
-e SECURE_AUTH_KEY=$RANDOM_KEY \
-e NONCE_KEY=$RANDOM_KEY \
-e LOGGED_IN_KEY=$RANDOM_KEY \
-e AUTH_SALT=$RANDOM_KEY \
-e SECURE_AUTH_SALT=$RANDOM_KEY \
-e LOGGED_IN_SALT=$RANDOM_KEY \
-e NONCE_SALT=$RANDOM_KEY \
-e WP_DEBUG=true \
-e DISABLE_WP_CRON=true \
-e ENABLE_HTTPS=true wordpress:5.7.2
```

Answer (score 2):

use this code in functions.php

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'f_force_ssl');

function f_force_ssl()
{
    if (!is_ssl()) 
    {
        wp_redirect('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . 
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to work for me, I had to comment out the if statement lines surrounding the line `$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';`

I am using Zevenet CE 5.9, which does not provide the options for x-forwarded-for or x-forwarded-proto, hence to put it behind the reverse proxy we just force https on this way :).